# replace "! " /" with "-" once

Tags: php

I have

```
$name = "Apple iPad 2 (32 GB) Wi-Fi / 3G Black 9.7" Tablet - MC774LLA";
```

How can I replace any of the following `""!/.,"` with a `"-"` once.

So it looks like

```
Apple-iPad-2-(32-GB)-Wi-Fi-3G-Black-9-7-Tablet-MC774LLA
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there supposed to be a double quote in the middle of that string? Is it supposed to be escaped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$beautifulName = preg_replace('/[!\/.,\s\-]+/', '-', $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name   = 'Apple iPad 2 (32 GB) Wi-Fi / 3G Black 9.7" Tablet - MC774LLA';
$name   = preg_replace("/-+/", '-', str_replace(array('"', '!', '.', ',', ' '), '-', $name));
```

Refer to http://uk.php.net/str_replace for more information.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to only display the "-" once. So it does not end up like Apple---iPad-- etc?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to use a regular expression and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$string = 'Apple iPad 2 (32 GB) Wi-Fi / 3G Black 9.7" Tablet - MC774LLA';
$string = preg_replace('/["!/., ]+/', '-', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compact multiple occurences, and also replace the spaces (as you didn't mention), then use a regex for simplicity:

```
$name = preg_replace('~[-/!"\s,...]+~', "-", $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = 'Apple iPad 2 (32 GB) Wi-Fi / 3G Black 9.7" Tablet - MC774LLA';
print preg_replace('/["!\/.,\s-]+/', '-', $name);
```